# MLKit detector process returns empty List<Face>

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I faced the following problem. I have an image taken from camera (bytearray). I need to get face info on this image. For this purpose I wrote the following code:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.size)

val image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0)

val options = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
    .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
    .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
    .build()

val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(options)

detector.process(image)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        println()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        it.printStackTrace()
    }
```

When I run the app success case is executed but the List in success case is always empty. So, why can it happen all the time?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the converted InputImage is malformed. Could you try to construct the InputImage from camera output(bytearray) directly? Please refer to [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/428a1d75b93ee84b1d783ea75059a45514af98a2/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/VisionProcessorBase.kt#L113) example.